# compare 2 arrays in c#

Tags: c#, arrays

Hi guys I need to compare 2 text files i.e:

File1:

```
MB-ASUSZ97K 
GPU-GTX780 
snd-sbaudigyfx 
WLAN-300
```

file2:

```
MB-ASUSZ97K 
//SERVER/drivers/asusz97k.exe 
PCI-FWI121 
//SERVER/drivers/fwi.exe 
GPU-GTX780 
//SERVER/drivers/gtx780.exe 
SOF-BULL1
//SERVER/drivers/bullguard.exe
snd-sbaudigyfx
//SERVER/drivers/sbfx.exe
Z97N-WIFI
//SERVER/drivers/z97nwifi.exe
WLAN-300
//SERVER/drivers/wlan300.exe
```

All i need to do is reference file1 to file2 and get links to copy drivers from the server to hdd.
I think i'll need 3 array to move links to it.
My quiestions is how do i reference them to get links?

Here is what i have so far (with the help of  the [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25241565/284240)):

```
void getDrivers()
{
    string path1 = "c:/testbase/65500.txt";
    string path2 = "c:/testbase/config.txt";

    var file1 = new HashSet<string>(File.ReadAllLines(path1));
    string line;
    var file2 = new System.IO.StreamReader(path2);
    Dictionary<string, string> links = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    while ((line = file2.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        string nextLine;
        if (file1.Contains(line) && (nextLine = file2.ReadLine()) != null)
            links[line] = nextLine;
         foreach (var kv in links)
             Console.WriteLine("Key: {0} Value:{1}", kv.Key, kv.Value);
    }
}
```

getting so far this:

```
Key: MB-ASUSZ97K     Value://SERVER/drivers/asusz97k.exe
Key: MB-ASUSZ97K     Value://SERVER/drivers/asusz97k.exe
Key: MB-ASUSZ97K     Value://SERVER/drivers/asusz97k.exe
Key: MB-ASUSZ97K     Value://SERVER/drivers/asusz97k.exe
Key: GPU-GTX780      Value://SERVER/drivers/gtx780.exe
Key: MB-ASUSZ97K     Value://SERVER/drivers/asusz97k.exe
Key: GPU-GTX780      Value://SERVER/drivers/gtx780.exe
Key: MB-ASUSZ97K     Value://SERVER/drivers/asusz97k.exe
Key: GPU-GTX780      Value://SERVER/drivers/gtx780.exe
Key: MB-ASUSZ97K     Value://SERVER/drivers/asusz97k.exe
Key: snd-sbaudigyfx  Value://SERVER/drivers/sbfx.exe
Key: MB-ASUSZ97K     Value://SERVER/drivers/asusz97k.exe
Key: GPU-GTX780      Value://SERVER/drivers/gtx780.exe
Key: snd-sbaudigyfx  Value://SERVER/drivers/sbfx.exe
Key: MB-ASUSZ97K     Value://SERVER/drivers/asusz97k.exe
Key: GPU-GTX780      Value://SERVER/drivers/gtx780.exe
Key: snd-sbaudigyfx  Value://SERVER/drivers/sbfx.exe
Key: MB-ASUSZ97K     Value://SERVER/drivers/asusz97k.exe
Key: GPU-GTX780      Value://SERVER/drivers/gtx780.exe
Key: snd-sbaudigyfx  Value://SERVER/drivers/sbfx.exe
Key: WLAN-300        Value://SERVER/drivers/wlan300.exe
```

but need this:

```
Key: MB-ASUSZ97K     Value://SERVER/drivers/asusz97k.exe
Key: GPU-GTX780      Value://SERVER/drivers/gtx780.exe
Key: snd-sbaudigyfx  Value://SERVER/drivers/sbfx.exe
Key: WLAN-300        Value://SERVER/drivers/wlan300.exe
```

Comment: Create a dictionary from file2 and look up items from file1?

Comment: answer below is working but not giving desired output. Still working on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the first file contains only the names whereas the second contains names followed by the links?

This should work:

```
var links = new Dictionary<string, string>();
var file1 = new HashSet<string>(File.ReadLines(path1));
var file2 = new System.IO.StreamReader(path2);
string line;
while ((line = file2.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    string nextLine;
    if (file1.Contains(line) && (nextLine = file2.ReadLine()) != null)
        links[line] = nextLine;
}
```

Now you've a dictionary where the key is the name and the value is the link.

This test:

```
foreach (var kv in links)
    Console.WriteLine("Key: {0} Value:{1}", kv.Key, kv.Value);
```

outputs:

```
Key: MB-ASUSZ97K     Value://SERVER/drivers/asusz97k.exe
Key: GPU-GTX780      Value://SERVER/drivers/gtx780.exe
Key: snd-sbaudigyfx  Value://SERVER/drivers/sbfx.exe
Key: WLAN-300        Value://SERVER/drivers/wlan300.exe
```

Comment: not completely sorted. It's giving a list of everything but there are multiple lines.

Comment: MB... is repeated 4 times then there is mix MB... and GPU... and SND... then at the end i get last 4 lines as i want them. English isn't my native language as well. Sorry if you don't understand me, doing my best!

Comment: @arti: edit your question and provide sample data which demonstrates this problem. Also show the desired result. If you've edited it you could leave a comment here, so that i can have a look.

Comment: my desired output is one provided by you, but i'm getting this: [link](http://1drv.ms/1r55N7L)

Comment: @arti: that's impossible since a `Dictionary<tKey, TValue>` cannot contain multiple equal keys as your output suggests. So i don't know which code you have used or how many dictionaries you're using. Do you have repeating keys? Then the value will always be overwritten at `links[line] = nextLine`. Show the real sample data.

Comment: edited code, see above. I'm new to stackoverflow if i'm doing something wrong here, apologize!

Comment: @arti: i thought that you wanted to add sample data which shows the incorrect result. But with the sample data above and your code i still get the desired result.

Comment: ok i'll tell you what i need.
i'm trying to make our installing software process automated, so each order has file with unique SKU (File1) so i thought when i create File2 with reference to drivers/software link on our internal server it could install these drivers in silent mode. I just can't reference them, i'm noob to be honest.

Comment: @arti: it still doesn't make sense, sorry. It's not important what you're actually trying to achieve. But you should show sample data which demonstrates the problem you're talking about. The sample data above yields two dictionary entries: 1)`ey: snd-sbaudigyfx Value://SERVER/drivers/sbfx.exe`
2)`Key: WLAN-300 Value://SERVER/drivers/wlan300.exe`
What is incorrect? It is confusing if you tell us that you currently get `<http://1drv.ms/1r55N7L>` but this line is not even part of your sample data.

Comment: this is link to the picture! http://1drv.ms/1r55N7L
i had it as a link, you changed it to the code confusing everyone!

Comment: @arti: i cannot copy/paste it, can it? Please edit your question to provide this sample data and not links to sites where we need to download something. I cannot copy/paste images and [links will rot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot) anyway.

Comment: @arti: sorry, i don't get it. Have you used the debugger to see what happens? Have you for example white-spaces(so f.e. spaces or tabs) in the line which makes them repeating? Then you need to use `Trim()` to remove them. You only show the desired and actual result above but not the sample data. If the sample data above (`File1...`+`File 2...`) is the real data it cannot produce the result. I've tested it with two files.

Comment: oh i'm being silly, sorry! as you see in my code foreach loop is in while loop. Debugger showed me my problem. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @arti: Well, now that you mention it, ... ;-) I'm glad that it works now.

Comment: next time i'll try to be more careful and pro! :)
thanks again!